# Haskell module import path navigation

Tags: haskell

I have a directory structure which goes something like this

```
a
- a.hs
- b
-- b.hs
- c
-- c.hs
```

I want to import c.hs in to b.hs but I can't work out how to go up a directory and in to b. Typically this would be something like `../c/c.hs`.

What is the Haskell way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you don't save "just code" but modules `module ModuleName where`.  Modules are saved under a file name and path that reflects the module name so you'd have file `ADirectory/A.hs` (note the capital letter at the start) which starts with `module ADirectory.A where` and same with the others.

After writing your code people collect the modules into the package. 
 Sometimes off-handedly called "cabalization" due to using the `cabal-install` tool (or the alternative, `stack`), this can be done with `cabal init` and making sure your cabal file lists each module.

Inside modules such as the file `ADirectory/A.hs`, you can import the other modules.  For example `A` can import `B` via `import BDirectory.B`.

Finally, if it isn't already obvious, the import statements refer to modules which the compiler must already have installed. It isn't possible to import something based on a file system path.